# Keep a process alive after logging out from local (not ssh) session

Tags: linux, centos, fedora

Is it possible to keep a server process running after I logout of the machine?

Normally I would use `screen`, `tmux`, or `nohup`, all of which work when I am NOT using ssh, but am using the machine locally. (It also is running the Gnome Desktop.)

So, is there anyway to start a server process when you are logged in locally to a machine?

Comment: All of the options you listed should work fine when you're logged in locally. What seems to be the problem with them?

Comment: I can disconnect from the screen just fine. However, when I log out, the screen session seems to die.

Comment: Are you able to start the process under another user account? It seems when you logout, it stops all running processes under your name.

Comment: There is only one user on the machine. If the server is started from ssh, it continues to run even after log out.

Comment: Which distro is this? There's probably some way to disable the part where it kills all your processes on logout...

Comment: The distro is Fedora.

Comment: Are you using the F25 alpha? We're trying a new systemd feature... and it has some quirks. What does `loginctl show-session -p KillUserProcesses` show you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of systemd 230, `KillUserProcesses` is enabled by default:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/97e5530cf2076a2b4fc55755917262607aaa6338

You can change this by editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, e.g. by setting `KillUserProcesses=no` to disable this behavior globally, or setting `KillExcludeUsers=<your-username>` to exclude your username from this behavior.

Or you can work around this on an ad hoc basis by starting your server process using `systemd-run --scope --user <executable>`. You can find more details about this in `Example 5. Start screen as a user service` towards the bottom of [systemd-run(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Debian Stretch and `KillUserProcesses` is disabled by default on my system, but `screen` would not survive a logout. After some experimentation, the following seems to keep the screen session running after logging out locally:

```
screen -m
```

or if you wish to detach right away

```
screen -m -d
```

I'm not sure why this is the case, but it seems to work for me.

Edit:

I did some more testing and it seems running screen with a command does not survive.  I started 4 sessions and detached from them if needed:

Before logout:

```
user    31365     1  0 16:20 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S mdc -m -d vim
user    31376     1  0 16:20 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S md -m -d
user    31391     1  0 16:20 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S mc -m vim
user    31399     1  0 16:21 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S m -m
```

After logging out and back in:

```
user    31376     1  0 16:20 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S md -m -d
user    31399     1  0 16:21 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S m -m
```

It looks like the two instances started with a command had terminated during the logout.  I attached to the remaining two sessions and started VIM, then detached and logged out again.  After logging back in, the sessions were still running and VIM was still running in each session.